# Exporting the same object that is required confuses mocha

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

I'm working on a node app that uses mocha to run unit tests.

When I run this command:

```
mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script --reporter spec ./test/unit/*-test.coffee
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unknown option --compilers
```

It seems mocha is confused, because it definitely has a compilers option. This error started happening when I added a new file to the project. It's the only output I can get mocha to generate. --debug does nothing.

Let's say I have a package called person installed. I want to configure this package globally so that I can import the configured object anywhere in my project. To do that, I import person, configure it as a driver, and then export it again.

However, when I import it (either in Car.coffee or Car-test.coffee), mocha fails with the above error.

Driver.coffee

```
driver = require 'person'
driver.setSkill "Drive"

module.exports = driver
```

Car.coffee

```
driver = require './driver'
...
```

Car-test.coffee

```
driver = require '../../src/driver'
...
```

Note that this works fine if I'm just compiling with coffee and running the node project. There's no issue importing it there. But when I run with mocha, it fails if I import the file.

I can't really pinpoint the error. It seems just like a bug in mocha, but maybe I'm doing something "bad" by exporting the same object that I import, and node is just more forgiving?

I'm using the latest version of mocha (1.13.0). Thanks!

**Edit:**

This doesn't fix the error, and is not ideal syntax-wise:

```
person = require 'person'

class driver
  constructor: ->
    person.setSkill "Drive"
    @person = person

module.exports = driver
```

Note that simply wrapping it in a plain object doesn't work.

**Edit 2:**

Here's something else that doesn't work:

configure-driver.coffee

```
configureDriver = (person) ->
  person.setSkill "Drive"

module.exports = configureDriver
```

car.coffee

```
driver = require('./configure-driver')(require 'person')
```

Mocha throws the same error as before.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? I wasn't able to reproduce this error with [this code](https://gist.github.com/maxbeatty/8107929)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late but hopefully it will help someone (I just spent an hour paging through mocha's source code to track this down).

Try that command instead (the important bit is the equal  sign after `--compilers`):

```
mocha --compilers=coffee:coffee-script --reporter spec ./test/unit/*-test.coffee
```

I ran into that bug while trying to create a new `grunt test` taks using **grunt-mocha-istanbul** and coffeescript test definitions. Strangely, if I ran the command directly in my shell it worked but using the grunt task I got the same error as you did.

Comment: Thanks I just had the same issue when I started using var program = require('commander');  , here my config:  node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers=coffee:coffee-script/register -w --recursive -R list tests

Answer (score 0):

It seems Mocha uses commander and it's global. In my case I had a script under the test directory that uses commander. It looks like Mocha executes the test scripts, parses mocha.opts, and then executes the specs. To fix it I just moved the scripts using commander out of the test dir and all was good.